# Convert pymysql query result with MySQL Decimal type to Python float

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, pymysql

I am relatively new to Python (3.x) and one of the confounding behaviors of the language is that Decimal and float seem to be distinct types (I presume here the difference is the usual one between double / float...).

Complicating the picture is that my Python logic reads/writes to MySQL records with fields defined as Decimal (with a variety of formats).

On the write-side, I finagled `pymysql` encoders like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pymysql

pymysql.converters.encoders[np.float64] = pymysql.converters.escape_float
pymysql.converters.conversions = pymysql.converters.encoders.copy()
pymysql.converters.conversions.update(pymysql.converters.decoders)
```

This helped, I believe, with persistence of Python Decimals to the MySQL records.

But on the read-side, there seems to be no obvious way to get Python `float`s when we read `Decimal` fields through pymysql queries.  (Maybe that would represent a downcast and therefore a possible loss of data.)

What do people do here?  Is the convention just to use Decimal types everywhere to circumvent these down/up-casting issues?  And what about the MySQL interface through pymysql?

My general thinking is that float/double behavior should just be automatic.  That the language imposes a distinction between float/double is probably a good thing; that code completely breaks because a simple `+` or `-` operand doesn't gracefully work with varying types is truly confounding, though.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

probably not helpful for the OP, but this may help with anyone else who finds themselves in a similar situation. You can ovveride the default decoders which is Decimal by default

```
import pymysql

query = """
    select * from db.table
"""

connection_string = {"host":"localhost","port":"3306","user":"user","password":"***","database":"db"}

conversions = pymysql.converters.conversions
conversions[pymysql.FIELD_TYPE.DECIMAL] = lambda x: float(x)
conversions[pymysql.FIELD_TYPE.NEWDECIMAL] = lambda x: float(x)
conn = pymysql.connect(
                host=connection_string.get("host"),
                user=connection_string.get("user"),
                password=connection_string.get("password"),
                db=connection_string.get("database"),
                charset="utf8",
                conv=conversions,
                cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor,
                autocommit=True
            )

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute(query)

results = cursor.fetchall()
```